# Unhandled exception has occurred in your application ... Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've facing when my pre developed apps open in another computer. This warning is shown and the application is not running.

> "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately. The type initializer for 'TopAuto.MAINMODULE' threw an exception."

Details is:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TopAuto.MAINMODULE' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
   at TopAuto.MAINMODULE..cctor()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TopAuto.MAINMODULE.checkServer()
   at TopAuto.FrmLogin.btnLogIn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\A Sale Software Project\TopAuto\TopAuto\Form\FrmLogin.vb:line 292
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8762 (QFE.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TopAuto
    Assembly Version: 22.0.7.14
    Win32 Version: 22.0.7.14
    CodeBase: file:///D:/newsoft/TopAuto.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.7057 (QFE.050727-7000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8770 (QFE.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8653 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8681 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8771 (QFE.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
DevComponents.DotNetBar2
    Assembly Version: 7.0.0.4
    Win32 Version: 7.0.0.4
    CodeBase: file:///D:/newsoft/DevComponents.DotNetBar2.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.7057 (QFE.050727-7000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8762 (QFE.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8773 (QFE.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.7057 (QFE.050727-7000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: It appears to be missing a file on a specific location. Please include the related code and where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Read what the exception text/message tells you: "_Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared [...]' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified._" Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: Why was this tagged VB6???

Answer (score 2):

The second paragraph is an answer to your question:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TopAuto.MAINMODULE' threw an exception. ---> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.** The system **cannot find the file specified.**

Although you have your application compiled into an executable file, it has some dependencies: beside .NET libraries (which have been loaded successfully as the message states) it requires some library called **CrystalDecisions.Shared** for dynamic linking.

This problem's solution is all but difficult: you have to either provide the application with the required dll, by copying it to the same directory where the executable resides (or to a corresponding relative path within the folder structure) or, which is the more portable but less updateable way, recompile the app and link it with the library statically. That would include your library to the executable itself, resulting in a single .exe file, which can be moved and copied on its own. Static linking generally results in a higher performance since your program can simply jump from one place to another without the need to dynamically load some libraries, but that may negligible and has nothing to do with your question.